# unable to get file name in struts2 file upload

Tags: struts2

I am new to Struts2. I am unable to get file name and path. Kindly help any one.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import nre.dao.DBconnection;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

 public class AddProperty extends ActionSupport
{

private String propertyid;
private String propertyname;
private String country;
private String state;
private String city;
private String description;
private File uploadphoto;
private String photofiletype;
private String photoname;

public String getPropertyid()
{
    return propertyid;
}
public void setPropertyid(String propertyid)
{
    this.propertyid = propertyid;
}
public String getPropertyname()
{
    return propertyname;
}
public void setPropertyname(String propertyname)
{
    this.propertyname = propertyname;
}
public String getCountry()
{
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(String country)
{
    this.country = country;
}
public String getState()
{
    return state;
}
public void setState(String state)
{
    this.state = state;
}
public String getCity()
{
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city)
{
    this.city = city;
}
public String getDescription()
{
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description)
{
    this.description = description;
}
public File getUploadphoto()
{
    return uploadphoto;
}
public void setUploadphoto(File uploadphoto)
{
    this.uploadphoto = uploadphoto;
}

public String getPhotofiletype() {
    return photofiletype;
}

public void setPhotofiletype(String photofiletype) {
    this.photofiletype = photofiletype;
}

public String getPhotoname() {
    return photoname;
}

public void setPhotoname(String photoname) {
    this.photoname = photoname;
}

public String execute(){

    DBconnection connection=new DBconnection();
    connection.getConnection();

    try{

        String filepath=connection.filepath;

        System.out.println("filepath : : "+filepath);
        System.out.println("photoname : : "+photoname);

        if(filepath!=null && photoname!=null){
            File filetocreate=new File(filepath,photoname);
            FileUtils.copyFile(uploadphoto, filetocreate);  
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        addActionError(e.getMessage());

        return INPUT;
    }

    String query ="insert into addproperty(propertyid,propertyname,propertycity,propertystate,propertycountry,addedby,addeddate,removeddate) values ('"+propertyid+"','"+propertyname+"','"+city+"','"+state+"','"+country+"','Parthi',now(),NULL)";
    connection.executeUpdate(query);

    System.out.println("Completed Inserting");

    return SUCCESS;

    //System.out.println("Class completed");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Action class should have the following three properties. 
• [inputName]File 
• [inputName]FileName 
• [inputName]ContentType

[inputName] is the name of the file tag(s) on the JSP. For example, if the file tag's name is uploadphoto, the properties will be as follows: 
• File uploadphotoFile  
• String uploadphotoFileName 
• String uploadphotoContentType

```
String filePath = servletRequest.getRealPath("/");
File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.uploadphotoFileName);
FileUtils.copyFile(this.uploadphotoFile, fileToCreate);
```

Comment: Now i am getting this issue can any one help me

java.lang.NullPointerException: Source must not be null
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:630)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:606)
    at com.nre.addproperty.AddProperty.execute(AddProperty.java:173)
Mar 25, 2013 2:14:03 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger info
INFO: Removing file uploadphoto loaction of your choice\upload__1451e278_13da0b7f253__8000_00000011.tmp

Comment: I had the same issue, the answer was almost correct, however, the three properties that you need are `private File [inputName];`, `private String  [inputName]FileName;`, `private String [inputName]ContentType;`

So the `java.io.File` property should have the same name as the one given in the `s:file`  tag.